# Reading card file in a Microsoft 365 environment

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, todo

I run a aviation schoolhouse and have to post updates to the airspace / new policy / new procedures for my pilots to follow. They will have to provide a user acknowledgment after they read the file or update. On paper, They are a "red" if they didn't read the card file or didn't acknowledge it. If they read the card file then they turn green and get to go fly. I have about 50 card files that one person will need to review one time to bring them to a green status - If a new reading card comes out I need it to turn them red to review that one document. We can build this in Access but I'm limited to Microsoft 365 environment (Online) and I need to make it dumb dumb proof and provide a green check mark or green file when the pilot has review all files so I as chief pilot will look at one line and say good to go. The files would be stored in a document library on SharePoint or attached to a MS To Do app or Planning app. I think I would need a list to output a red or green mark on one person. I have about 100 aviators to look over.

Any ideas / direction?

Thank you!